# Unable to change admin prefix in cakephp 1.3

Tags: php, cakephp

I have built admin of my cakephp site using prefix 'webadmin'. Now I need to change this to something like 'aRRT6nnf'.

I changed the admin prefix in core.php, routes.php and even changes the filenames in views folder but this gives the following error:

```
Error: The requested address '/aRRT6nnf' was not found on this server.
```

I made following changes to accomplish this:

```
//core.php
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('aRRT6nnf'));

//routes.php
Router::connect('/aRRT6nnf', array('controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index', 'prefix'=>'aRRT6nnf', 'aRRT6nnf'=>true));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed the prefixes on your controller methods

When using admin routing in Cake 1.3 your controller actions need to be prefixed with the route they pertain to for example take route `admin` your Dashboard controller should be something like this

```
class DashboardController extends AppController
{

    public admin_index() {

    }
```

So in your specific case you would need to change them to

```
public aRRT6nnf_index() {

}
```

Comment: Yes, I changed the prefixes on controller methods but it does not work.